# managing multiple mesos marathon json configurations for deployment

Tags: json, deployment, docker, containers, marathon

So I am using Mantl.io for our environment.  Things are going very well and we are now past the POC phase and starting to think about how we are going to handle continuous delivery.  Obviously automation is key.  Maybe my approach or thinking is wrong but I am trying to figure out a way to manage the json I will pass to marathon to deploy the docker containers from our registry via a jenkins job call.  We have various environments (testing, perf, prod, etc)  and in each of these environments I will have my 30+ microservices needing different variables set for cpu, memory, environment variables, etc.

So I am just not sure the best approach for taking my docker containers and linking them with what could be maybe 10 or more different configurations per microservice depending on the environment.

Are there tools for building, managing, versioning, linking containers to configs to environments?  I just can't seem to find anything in this realm and that leads me to believe I am headed down the wrong path.

Thanks

Comment: Hi I too have the same scenario where I have to deploy the microservices application on different environments and change the json configuration . Right now I am trying to build the tool of my own . Do you have any ideas,suggestions or any tool in mind you found yet which can help me in my venture?